# Geometry problems about circumcircle

Tags: geometry

The incircle of triangle ABC passes sides AB at C', BC at A', and CA at B'. If a line parallel to BC was drawn such that it passes through A, and D is the intersection point of that line and the extension of A'C', prove that DB' is perpendicular to B'A'.

Is there like a general theorem to help solve this or is this just solvable using algebra (coordinates on the Cartesian plane)? I tried using algebra and it was kinda messy, and I can't really find a way to solve this using geometry.

Comment: For me, it's clearly an angle hunting problem; by algebra you can consider particular cases (in $\Bbb C, B=0, C=4, A=3i,I=1+i, A'=1,C'=i$)but it actually risks becoming quickly complicated in the general case.

Comment: Agreed with Stephane Jaouen that it is an angle chasing problem. The problem is best solved by geometric approach.

Comment: Bashing isn’t hard at all, IMO. Easily compute $A’,B’,C’$ by using the side ratios (s-a, s-b, s-c). Cartesian coordinates work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\widehat A, \beta=\widehat B$ and $\gamma =\widehat C$ : $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180°$, so $\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2}=90°.$

$\widehat{A'B'I}=\frac{\gamma}{2}$ and $\widehat{IB'C'}=\frac{\alpha}{2}$; It will therefore suffice to show that $\widehat{C'B'D}=\frac{\beta}{2}.$

1. $\widehat{DAB}=\beta$ and $\widehat{DC'A}=90-\frac{\beta}{2}$; so, in $DAC', \widehat{C'DA}=180-\beta-(90-\frac{\beta}{2})=90-\frac{\beta}{2}$; so, $C'AD$ is isoscele and $AC'=AD.$
2. Likewise, $AC'B'$ is isoscele and $AC'=AB'.$
3. So, $ADB'$ is isoscele . But $\widehat{DB'A}=\frac{180-\alpha-\beta}{2}=\frac{\gamma}{2} $ and $\widehat{C'B'D}=\widehat{C'B'A}-\widehat{DB'A}=90-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{\gamma}{2}=\frac{\beta}{2}$

Q.E.D.
[image]

Comment: Nice solution, Stephane Jaouen. Here is one observation for sharing. Since $AD=AC'=AB'$, $A$ is the circumcenter of  $\Delta B'CD$. Noting that $\angle DAC' = \angle ABC = \beta$ and $\angle CB'D=\frac {\angle DAC'}{2}$, we conclude that $\angle CB'D=\frac{\beta}{2}$

Comment: Thanks :). $A$ is the center of the circle $B'C'D$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung : you use $\widehat{DAC'}$ central angle and $\widehat{C'B'D}$ inscribed angle : nice :).